# PLESK Windows - Psaadm and Psacln privileges

Tags: windows, privileges, plesk

I've got problem with setting privileges for psaadm and psacln accounts in Plesk for Windows. I've used DiskSecurity to protect my files against psacln users group. Unfortunately when I'm logged in Plesk as customer and I'm executing my php script client have permissions to read my "protected file". Permissions for my files in Windows is Full Access for psaadm and Full Deny for psacln group.

Additionally I noticed that if I deny permissions for psaadm, no one can read this file (psaadm and all psacln accounts).

Is there any other working well way to protect files against customer accounts?

Answer (score 0):

There is possible to customize permissions by extending permission rules.

Check this doc for more information:

http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP12/12.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-win-advanced-administration-guide/index.htm?fileName=49498.htm